# Can I disable code folding in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, folding

I want to disable code folding in WebStorm. It's possible to turn off the folding indicators, but the folding itself still works. I'd like to be rid of the whole thing, so it's impossible to activate it in any way. Is this possible?

(There aren't any obvious options, but I'm hopeful there's something I've missed...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the WebStorm preferences there is a section for folding. There you can enable/disable folding for all different types of code. Personally, I have all my folding disabled as well. Hope this helps!

FYI:
Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding

Comment: Thanks. I've unticked all of those, but I can still collapse stuff by pressing Ctrl+-.

Comment: @TomSeddon Those settings there are for default code folding (which happens on file opening) -- they do not affect manual one. So, to disable folding when you press `Ctrl+.` (for example) just remove keyboard shortcuts from appropriate actions in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`

Comment: I am then pretty much signing myself up for having to use import/export settings to manage this stuff, plus SVN or whatever to share the files, rather than being able to tick one box on each computer on which I use WebStorm. But if that is the only option, it's the only option. Looks like I'll just have to remain unhappy. Thanks!